# Openshift.com - unable to connect with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

I am trying to establish a connection with mysql-5.1, but it shows errors like "could not connect" or when I change the hostname "Could not connect: No such file or directory".

My file reads like this

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
printf("MySQL server version: %s\n", mysql_get_server_info());
?>
```

Tried changing mysql_connect to mysqli_connect. No difference.

1) The Mysql is running(as per the interface).

2) tried various rhc commands to restart the app, restart|reload the cartridge etc. - no errors while doing so."eg.Mysql-5.1 restart...done".

3) tried pinging the $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST and it worked.

4) tried telneting the $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST and it says connection established and some garbled text.

5) ps aux | grep "mysql"
4213      21721  0.0  0.0 103252   828 pts/0    S+   10:56   0:00 grep mysql

### 6)mysql> status

/usr/bin/mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:          4
Current database:
Current user:           xxxxxxxxxxxxx@xx.xx.xx.xx
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.1.73 Source distribution
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.rhcloud.com via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    latin1
Conn.  characterset:    latin1
TCP port:               50986
Uptime:                 18 min 40 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 4  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 17  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 4  Queries per second avg: 0.3

I changed the code to

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');

/*
 * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
 * BUT $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

/*
 * Use this instead of $connect_error if you need to ensure
 * compatibility with PHP versions prior to 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

again the same error.

Can somebody help me out? Even phpmyadmin code says "could not connect to mysql".

thanks
Ganesh Kumar

Comment: Please dont use mysql_ extension..go for mysqli or PDO instead...maybe you username and password on the php script are wrong...which user and password did you use to connect to the mysql console...use those same on your php script

Comment: username and pass were the same as given while creating the cartridge. let me just check with mysqli_

Comment: Should I use localhost or "534xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx.rhcloud.com" as specified in the $OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST?

Comment: tried both. Here, tested with 534xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx.rhcloud.com" to get this error "Connect Error (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known". And tried with localhost to get "Connect Error (2002) No such file or directory". Any idea?

Comment: You should use connection parameters available as environment variables on your openshift box.  OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST, OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME, OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD, OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME (as database name).

Comment: It worked after adding the port number.Thanks :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL 5.5 db connection in Openshift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045035/php-mysql-5-5-db-connection-in-openshift)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following:

```
<?php
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database */
define('DB_NAME', $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME']);

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME']);

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD']);

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'] . ':' . $_ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT']);

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
printf("MySQL server version: %s\n", mysql_get_server_info());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by following code.

```
define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
define('DB_PORT', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'));
define('DB_USER', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
define('DB_PASS', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'));
define('DB_NAME', getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME'));

$dbhost = constant("DB_HOST"); // Host name 
$dbport = constant("DB_PORT"); // Host port
$dbusername = constant("DB_USER"); // Mysql username 
$dbpassword = constant("DB_PASS"); // Mysql password 
$db_name = constant("DB_NAME"); // Database name
```